# Installing django rest framework kills the server

Tags: django

I work on ubuntu for creating a django app. Everything went well untill i install rest_framework and add this app to allowed apps list in settings.py Once i did this server started to show internal server errors. Somebody could  help on it ?

Comment: Use debug mode to see the error behind

Comment: show us your errors

Comment: @ArmenTsaturyan website dont resolve later.

Comment: @ArmenTsaturyan Internal Server Error

The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was unable to complete your request.